# Set pointers to a string of char in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array (POINTS) with a length >20M of the following structure (point) and would like to save it in a binary file to read it afterwards in a different program:

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;
  unsigned char namelength;  
} point;

if((POINTS = (point *) malloc (N * sizeof(point))) == NULL){        
    printf("when allocating memory for the points vector\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

What I'm doing is the following; First I'm creating a variable `namestot` to know how many characters I have in total (some names may be empty):

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) namestot += POINTS[i].namelength;
```

Then I'm writing the array in a file:

```
if ((fin = fopen(name, "wb")) == NULL){
    printf("the output binary data file cannot be open\n");
    exit(0);
}

for ( i=0; i < N; i++){
    if (POINTS[i].namelength){
        if( fwrite(point[i].name, sizeof(char), POINTS[i].namelength, fin) != POINTS[i].namelength){
            printf("when writing names to the output binary data file\n");
            exit(0);
        }       
    }
}
```

With that I create the file without issues. Now we change to another program with the binary file saved, so we open and read it:

```
if ((fin = fopen (argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
    printf("the data file does not exist or cannot be opened\n");
    exit(0);
}
//Here we allocate memory again for the POINTS vector
    if((POINTS = (point *) malloc (N * sizeof(point))) == NULL){        
        printf("when allocating memory for the points vector\n");
        exit(0);
    }

if((allnames = (char *) malloc (namestot * sizeof(char))) == NULL){
    printf("when allocating memory for the names vector");  
    exit(0);
}

if (fread(allnames, sizeof(char), namestot, fin) != namestot){
        printf("when reading names from the binary data file\n");
        exit(0);
    }

//Setting pointers to names
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    if(POINTS[i].namelength > 0){
        POINTS[i].name = allnames; 
        allnames += POINTS[i].namelength;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to read the first non-empty name the program prints the entire array of names, any advice on how to set the pointers to the mesan to have the POINTS array as I had it in the first program?

Thanks!

PS: if there's any non-declared variable I've probably forgot to paste it here, that's not the issue.

Comment: On your PS: so this is not a [mcve]? I cannot copy your code, save it in a file, and compile it? Even if I paste all these separate pieces together, in order, and add a `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing variable length strings to files, so when you read it you need to know length of individual string

You may decide to include length string along with the string to write in the file or ensure you write trailing '\0' to indicate earlier string ends and new one begins from next byte, your reader program will have to parse the strings accordngly

Comment: For every string I'm stating their individual length when writing to the bin file (POINTS[i].namelength) if that's what you mean, would it maybe work better with the '\0'?

Comment: I mean writing "5Jordi", instead of "Jordi" so that you know length of "Jordi" is 5 when you read it back, another option i mentioned is write '\0' to file,  fwrite(point[i].name, sizeof(char), POINTS[i].namelength+1, fin) should do that if namelength has corect string length, in both the cases you need to parse out each individually when you read them back

Comment: Amazing, it worked with fwrite(point[i].name, sizeof(char), POINTS[i].namelength+1, fin)! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

> `prints` the entire array of names

Sounds like because you do not tell your program the end of each name, print `char *` stop when meet a `\0` .